# License expired when running through cron

Tags: php, cron, ioncube

Im running a PHP web system, with some files encoded with Ioncube. When I run the script from the browser's direction bar, it runs perfectly. When I run it from a cron job (php -q mypath/myscript.php) I get this emailed to me: 
**Fatal error**:  License expired in **Unknown** on line **0**

Why is this happening? License should be perpetual, but Im surprised about the difference between running it through url and through cron.

Comment: Did you include the `zend_extension=....` in the `php.ini` used by your PHP CLI? Some systems use a seperate `php.ini` for the CLI

Comment: _How to check what ini file PHP CLI is using_ Do a `> php --ini` and it will tell you where it is getting its ini file from

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did that and it's using the same php.ini that the browser is using.

Comment: Did you try contacting the script provider, and/or did you get it resolved?